# XSLT - For-each-group

Tags: xslt

This is a really basic question, but I'm not understanding how the for-each-group works. I want to combine adjacent top-level sections that don't have a sub section into a list. If there are sections WITH subsections I want to treat those differently, leaving the top level intact and combining the sub-sections into a list. I don't want to mix these up.

**Source XML**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <body>
     <sec>
        <title>A1</title>
        <p>Stuff A 1</p>
     </sec>
     <sec>
        <title>A2</title>
        <p>Stuff A 2</p>
     </sec>
     <sec>
        <title>A3</title>
        <p>Stuff A 3</p>
        <sec>
           <title>B1</title>
           <p>Stuff B1</p>
        </sec>
        <sec>
           <title>B2</title>
           <p>Stuff B2</p>
        </sec>
     </sec>
     <sec>
        <title>A4</title>
        <p>Stuff A 4</p>
     </sec>
  </body>
```

**Desired Result**

```
  <body>
     <list>
           <list-item><title>A1</title><p>Stuff A 1</p></list-item>
           <list-item><title>A2</title><p>Stuff A 2</p></list-item>
     </list>
     <sec>
        <title>A3</title>
        <p>Stuff A 3</p>
        <list>
          <list-item><title>B1</title><p>Stuff B1</p></list-item>
          <list-item><title>B2</title><p>Stuff B2</p></list-item>
        </list>
     </sec>
     <list>
        <list-item><title>A4</title><p>Stuff A 4</p></list-item>
     </list>
  </body>
```

**XSLT fragment**
This is definitely not correct. Also, it is not the only way I've tried, just the least messy to post. The way I *think* for-each-group should work I keep getting the error `An empty sequence is not allowed as the @group-adjacent attribute of xsl:for-each-group`. So this is just a snippet to get someone who knows what they are doing started.

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

        <!-- Identity Template -->
        <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="default" mode="#all">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates mode="#current"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

        <!-- Make top level body tag -->
        <xsl:template match="body">
            <body>
                <xsl:for-each-group select="sec[not(sec)]" group-adjacent=".">
                    <list>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                    </list>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
          </body>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="sec[not(sec)]">
            <list-item>
                <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
            </list-item>
        </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="sec" group-adjacent="exists(child::sec)">
```

which will give a group of `sec` elements that have a `sec` child, followed by a group that don't, and so on.

Within the `for-each-group` you may need to do `<xsl:choose><xsl:when test="child::sec">...` to apply different processing to the two kinds of group.